# How to use cut to print only a single line of command output?

Tags: shell, text, command, line, cut

I've written a shell script for testing purposes which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo 'line 1\n line2\n line3'
```

I am trying to print only a single line by using the cut command like so:

```
echo $(./myScript.sh | cut -d$'\n' -f1)
```

In the above example, my intention is for it to print 'line1'. Replacing -f1 with -f2 would have it print 'line2' instead, or so I thought.

Instead, my output looks like this:

```
line1 line2 line3
```

Similarly, if I change the delimiter from $'\n' to something else, like so:

```
echo $(./myScript.sh | cut -d'e' -f1)
```

The output becomes:

```
lin lin lin
```

So it appears that it is printing the first field before any delimiters for *each line* instead of the entire output of myScript.sh as a whole. How can I get the cut command to work for the entire string instead of each individual line? Alternatively, what other command might work better for this purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: I have found another way of doing it that looks like this:

`echo $(./myScript.sh | head -1)` 
for the first line, and `echo $(./myScript.sh | head -2 | tail -1)` for the second line. For the third line you would do `echo $(./myScript.sh | head -3 | tail -1)`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way of doing it that looks like this:

```
echo $(./myScript.sh | head -1)              # for the first line
echo $(./myScript.sh | head -2 | tail -1)    # for the second line
echo $(./myScript.sh | tail -1)    # for the third line
```